# How to pass parameters from a yaml file to a constructor, without expicitly mentioning each one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, yaml, bunny

I have this initialiser script for setting my RabbitMq connection using Bunny:

```
require 'yaml'
config = YAML.load_file('config/rabbitmq.yml')

puts config[Rails.env]
# $bunny = Bunny.new(config[Rails.env])

$bunny = Bunny.new(:host => config[Rails.env]["host"],
         :vhost => config[Rails.env]["vhost"],
         :user => config[Rails.env]["user"],
         :password => config[Rails.env]["password"],
)

$bunny.start
$bunny_channel = $bunny.create_channel
```

The contents of `config[Rails.env]` are:

```
{"<<"=>nil, "host"=>"spotted-monkey.rmq.cloudamqp.com", "user"=>"myuser", "password"=>"mypassord", "vhost"=>"myvhost"}
```

The verbose syntax of the `Bunny.new` command works correctly. However, when I comment out the verbose block, and leave this syntax:

```
$bunny = Bunny.new(config[Rails.env])
```

I get the following error message:

```
session.rb:296:in `rescue in start': Could not establish TCP connection to any of the configured hosts (Bunny::TCPConnectionFailedForAllHosts)
```

I was expecting it to work, since the keys are the same in both cases. Is there any way to call the constructor without specifying each parameter explicitly?

I tried to remove the `"<<"=>nil` line from the yaml file, with no change in behaviour.

Comment: Hey @user0000001, is this in `application.rb`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by initialiser script. Maybe I'm mistaken and it's in `config/initializers`?

Comment: @PrimeTimeTran: Yes, it was a script in `config/initializers`, that initializes the bunny connection. If you use the same script, remove the line `$bunny_channel = $bunny.create_channel` from the initialiser to the consumer to avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: I feel ya, thanks for the pointer. Would you mind giving me one more pointer?

I have my connection set up using a worker. I consume the message via another worker. 

This is my code: http://prntscr.com/i6pami
I confirm that my rabbitmq.server is on: http://prntscr.com/i6paye
There doesn't seem to be any messages being received: http://prntscr.com/i6pb5q

This worked fine when I was using CloudAMQP.

Comment: @PrimeTimeTran: I can't look into it right now, but you could ask a new question with this problem. Be sure to create a good MVCE prior to posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having look into source code I found this:

```
def hostnames_from(options)
  options.fetch(:hosts_shuffle_strategy, @default_hosts_shuffle_strategy).call(
    [ options[:hosts] || options[:host] || options[:hostname] || DEFAULT_HOST ].flatten
  )
end
```

It seems it is expecting a symbol `:host` not, string `'host'` which is practicaly the only difference between two ways you're calling initializer. Try:

```
config = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new YAML.load_file('config/rabbitmq.yml')
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the implementation of `Bunny.new` relies on the fact that the options can be accessed via symbol keys, but you get back string keys from `YAML.load_file`. You can fix that by using [`Hash#with_indifferent_access`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)

```
$bunny = Bunny.new(config[Rails.env].with_indifferent_access)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This also works correctly, but BroiSatse answered a minute earlier :)